# Extract a path to file from a URL which has parameters in it

Tags: android

So, I am trying to extract a path to a mp4 file from a URL. The problem is that they have parameters appended to it after a `?`.
Eg: `www.example.com/video.mp4?w=1280&h=720`
Now, what I do is extract substring as follows:

```
String fileNameWithParam = f.getVideoURL().substring(f.getVideoURL().lastIndexOf("/")+1);
String fileNameWithoutParam = fileNameWithParam.substring(0, fileNameWithParam.indexOf("?"));
fileName = fileNameWithoutParam;
```

Which works when the video URL **has** parameters appended and doesn't work when it does not have parameters appended to it.

Can someone please suggest a more general way to extract path to files from URL ? (without a specific file extension)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
final String path = new URL(f.getVideoURL()).getPath();
```

Comment: That would still have the `?..&..&` parameters appended right ?

Comment: No it will just return the path.